# MINIX 3 - server print information

Tags: c, server, minix

I am trying to modify the sched server and have been attempting to have it print out some information to stdout or stderr but without luck. I tried printf, fprintf, sprintf, puts, fputs. Any ideas on how I should do this? I am starting to think that for whatever reason it's not possible to have the server print something out even though it has printfs in it.

I tried adding these in schdule_process, start_scheduling and balance_queues.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void balance_queues(minix_timer_t *tp)
{
    struct schedproc *rmp;
    int proc_nr;

    printf("Test prinf\n");
    fprintf(stdout, "Test fprintf stdout\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "Test fprintf stderr\n");
    puts("Test puts\n");
    fputs("Test fputs stdout", stdout);
    fputs("Test fputs stderr", stderr);

    for (proc_nr=0, rmp=schedproc; proc_nr < NR_PROCS; proc_nr++, rmp++) {
        if (rmp->flags & IN_USE) {
            if (rmp->priority > rmp->max_priority) {
                rmp->priority -= 1; /* increase priority */
                schedule_process_local(rmp);
            }
        }
    }

    set_timer(&sched_timer, balance_timeout, balance_queues, 0);
}
```

Here's the balance_queues function I tried. I am pretty sure this is not a problem with my code instead something with minix which I don't yet understand. I've spend the last 2 hours reading and searching Tanenbaums and Woodhulls "The Minix book - Operating Systems, design and implementation" third edition but couldn't find anything. From what I understand this function should be called every 5 seconds to balance the queues but I there's nothing being printed to the command line!

Comment: No source, no fix - [mcve]